# Populate nested property after filtering

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a nested document that looks like this.

```
{
    "someReference": "Foo",
    "propA": [
        { "_id": "1234..." },
        { "_id": "af94..." }
    ],
    "propB": [
        {
            "_id": "8c34...",
            "refToOneA": "af94..."
        },
        // more of those here
    ]
}
```

The schema looks like this.

```
const propASchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    // other data
});
const propA = mongoose.model('propA', propASchema);


const propBSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true },
    refToOneA: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: propA
    }
});


const DataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    someReference: String,
    propA: [propASchema],
    propB: [propBSchema]
});
const Data = mongoose.model('Data', DataSchema);
```

Now I want to fetch `propB` filtered by some data and populate the `refToOneA`. The code for filtering looks something like this:

```
const filtered = await Data.findOne(
    { someReference: providedReference },
    {
        propB: {
            $filter {
                input: '$propB',
                cond: {
                    $and: someConditions
}}}});
```

This works fine and I get the correctly filtered output. Now I still need to populate the `refToOneA` property.

I have tried various things, e.g.

```
await Data.populate(filtered, 'refToOneA');
```

But whatever I try, I either get an error

> Cannot populate path [...] because it is not in your schema. Set the strictPopulate option to false to override.

or the `refToOneA` stays as it is (i.e. `"af94..."` in the example above) or the `refToOneA` is `null`.

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide the model schema?

Comment: Yes sure, I have added the schema.

Comment: In the mongoose docs I found the following: _Population is the process of automatically replacing the specified paths in the document with document(s) from other collection(s)._ The way I understand this, there is no way to populate subdocuments from the same collection. Is that correct?

Comment: I took a different route now, since this doesn't seem to be possible. I will leave the question as is, if somebody still wants to answer. Maybe the answer will help somebody else in the future.